WPF - Issues with populating and binding data to DataGridComboBoxColumn
I'm learning .NET and WPF, while also working on a personal project. I'm trying to setup a DataGridComboBoxColumn in a DataGrid, however I'm getting multiple errors and I can't find the answer, despite having looked through many different posts/answers.
I referred to this page, however, I'm getting multiple errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
What I've tried

Restarted Visual Studio.
Closed Visual Studio and deleted .vs folder.
Set Project Configuration from Debug to Release.
Unloaded and Reloaded Project.

Error List

Error   XDG0031 Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.  TestInterface   C:\..\..\..\TestInterface\MainWindow.xaml   11  
Error   XDG0023 A null or zero length string does not represent a valid Type.   TestInterface   C:\..\..\..\TestInterface\MainWindow.xaml   13  
Error   XDG0010 Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.  TestInterface   C:\..\..\..\TestInterface\MainWindow.xaml   25  
Error   XDG0008 The name "MenuItems" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:TestInterface". TestInterface   C:\..\..\..\TestInterface\MainWindow.xaml   13  

C# Code
namespace TestInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<HardwareTest>? hardwareTestList;
        List<string> hardwareList = new List<string>()
        {
            "Speaker",
            "Camera",
            "Microphone",
            "Wif",
            "Bluetooth",
            "Screen",
            "USB Ports",
            "Ethernet Port",
            "Aux Port",
            "SD Port",
            "Keyboard",
            "VGA",
            "Display Port",
            "HDMI",
            "Battery",
            "Finger Print"
        };
        public enum MenuItems
        {
            none,
            manual,
            automated
        };
        public class HardwareTest
        {
            public string? Hardware { get; set; }
            public MenuItems menuItems { get; set; }
            public Uri? TestPath { get; set; }
            public string? TestResult { get; set; }

            // constructor
            // a method which gets called once the class is initialized
            public HardwareTest(string? Hardware, MenuItems menuItems, Uri? TestPath, string? TestResult)
            {
                this.Hardware = Hardware;
                this.menuItems = menuItems;
                this.TestPath = TestPath;
                this.TestResult = TestResult;
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hardwareTestList = new ObservableCollection<HardwareTest>();
            for (int i = 0; i < hardwareList.Count; i++)
            {
                hardwareTestList.Add(new HardwareTest(hardwareList[i].ToString(), MenuItems.none, null, null));
            }
            dg1.ItemsSource = hardwareTestList;
        }
    }
}

XAML Code
<Window x:Class="TestInterface.MainWindow"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestInterface"
        Title="Test Interface" Height="500" Width="600" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="WhiteSmoke" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:MenuItems" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
       <DataGrid Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Test Type" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MenuItems}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />
      </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


Where is the property TestType declared?

As a note, the ObservableCollection is entirely redundant. You can as well write dg1.ItemsSource = hardwareList;. And ItemsSource="{Binding}" is of course also pointless when you assign the ItemsSource property in code.

@SirRufo That should be MenuItems I changed it because I thought that the previous name TestType was conflicting with the namespace TestInterface
